# Google Calendar APIv3 - how to handle incoming resource change notification using webhook?

Tags: php, api, calendar, watch

Using **Google APIv3** I wish to synchronize my **PHP** webapp calendar with **Google Calendar** by creating a notification channel using a webhook on my server. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) of Google I did the necessary preparations (defining and validating webhook, creating the notification channel) in order to receive status update information from the Calendar using the [watch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch) method.

My issue is that I cannot figure out what to do with the incoming information - as per my understanding and as stated in these docs, my webhook should be notified not only about the fact of change, but it should get the actual change as well so I can avoid unnecessary processing. Unfortunately, the [know-how](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#receiving-notifications) on receiving these notification are quite vague and I cannot find where to look for the nature of change made to the Calendar resource.

Am I missing something? Do I have to [get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) the resource using the identifier returned to the webhook and "manually" check differences or there is some technique I can use to [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) (or even more preferred [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch), but I also do not understand how to do that in PHP) the changed Calendar resource on my webapp side? Is PHP even a suitable language to implement this?

Comment: It's all about HTTP requests (and there is a full PHP SDK for Google APIs available if you prefer not to write the requests yourself) so there's no reason you can't use PHP

Comment: `as per my understanding and as stated in these docs, my webhook should be notified not only about the fact of change, but it should get the actual change as well`...and have you experienced something different in reality? What is received when you test this?

Comment: @ADyson is [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) the php  PHP SDK You mentioned? I cannot find these 'preset' HTTP requests, maybe I'm looking at the wrong place..

Comment: Yes it is. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#examples has some examples (using methods from other APIs, but you get the idea). Quick example of a calendar API call: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php. Further on, https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#making-requests explains that the classes are autogenerated and map directly to the JSON in the API documentation, so it shouldn't be too hard to work out what functions are available to use. I recommend reading the whole readme.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry I did not see Your second comment yesterday, so I couldn't react. I recreated the HTTP POST communication using OOP methods from the SDK You recommended, and the code looks better, however when I change something in Google Calendar I still receive nothing, not even the JSON object described in the documentation. My webhook is simply writing `"POST ::: " . var_dump($_POST) . "GET ::: " . var_dump($_GET)` to a txt file, but the txt file only receives the text part ("POST ::: and GET :::") so I assume no POST nor GET was made to the webhook, only a call with a data I did not catch.

Comment: `I assume no POST nor GET was made`...are you sure? a var_dump command will always output _something_, even if the object it's dumping is empty. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cde71b37fc8f47402e3e7dd73c909a02f7c24eaf . So you ought to be seeing something as well as the text. And https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#receiving-notifications explicitly says it will make a POST request to your endpoint.

Comment: Ah but also, I just noticed, if you read a bit lower down, it says "Notification messages posted by the Google Calendar API to your receiving URL do not include a message body". And just above it, it lists all the headers it will send containing the data. Bit of a bizarre way to do it IMHO but it's fairly clear. in PHP $_POST only contains the body of the request. You need to read from the headers to get your data - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: It looks like you'd then need to fetch the resource itself to see exactly what's changed. One of the headers incudes the URL of the resource, another contains the ID.